# How to get the stdout and stderr for subprocess.call?

Tags: python

I'm using `subprocess.call`, and I need to get the output for stdout and stderr. How can I do this?

Notice [check_output()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

> Note Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function. 
>   As the pipes are not being read in the current process, the child process may block 
>   if it generates enough output to a pipe to fill up the OS pipe buffer.

My call might produce a lot of output, so what would be a safe way to get the output?

Comment: `check_output` will actually do what you want, unless you need to separate it. It's telling you not to actually use `subprocess.PIPE` as the arguments for `stdout` and `stderr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this would work:

```
f = file('output.txt','w')
g = file('err.txt','w')

p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=f, stderr=g)

f.close()
g.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a file object opened for writing and pass that as `sdtout` and `stderr`.